# zipline-reloaded demean by sector is not working correctly

Tags: quandl, zipline

I am using zipline-reloaded with 'quandl' bundle. I am trying to construct a simple 1-year momentum factor that I want it demeaned by sector. It gives me errors on indexing as will be explained below.
Bear with me for the explanation as zipline is already lengthy to use.

First, I generate prices dataset using the below snippet

```
bundle_name = 'quandl'
trading_calendar = get_calendar('NYSE')
universe_end_date = pd.Timestamp('2016-01-05')
years=5 #used to specify start date as offset from end date to get data retrieved from 'Quandl'
field = 'close' #field from OHLCV fields
domain = US_EQUITIES
universe = AverageDollarVolume(window_length=120).top(500)
pipeline = Pipeline(screen=universe, domain=domain)

bundle_data = bundles.load(bundle_name)

def choose_loader(column):
    if column not in USEquityPricing.columns:
        raise Exception('Column not in USEquityPricing')
    return pricing_loader
    
def get_pricing(data_portal, trading_calendar, assets, start_date, end_date, field=field):
    end_dt = pd.Timestamp(end_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')) + pd.offsets.CustomBusinessDay()
    start_dt = pd.Timestamp(start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')) + pd.offsets.CustomBusinessDay()
    end_b = trading_calendar.closes.index.get_loc(end_dt)
    str_b = trading_calendar.closes.index.get_loc(start_dt)
    return data_portal.get_history_window(assets=assets, end_dt=end_dt, bar_count=end_b-str_b, frequency='1d', field=field, data_frequency='daily')

pricing_loader = USEquityPricingLoader(bundle_data.equity_daily_bar_reader, bundle_data.adjustment_reader,None)
engine = SimplePipelineEngine(default_domain=domain, get_loader=choose_loader, asset_finder=bundle_data.asset_finder)
universe_tickers = engine.run_pipeline(pipeline, universe_end_date, universe_end_date).index.get_level_values(1).values.tolist()
data_portal = DataPortal(bundle_data.asset_finder, trading_calendar=trading_calendar, 
                         first_trading_day=bundle_data.equity_daily_bar_reader.first_trading_day, equity_minute_reader=None, 
                         equity_daily_reader=bundle_data.equity_daily_bar_reader, adjustment_reader=bundle_data.adjustment_reader)
prices = get_pricing(data_portal, trading_calendar, universe_tickers, universe_end_date - pd.DateOffset(years=years), universe_end_date)
```

Now to check the 'prices' data frame, it gives the below columns and rows showing data (rows deleted here for irrelevance):

```
Equity(0 [A])   Equity(2 [AAL]) Equity(7 [AAP]) Equity(8 [AAPL])    Equity(12 [ABBV])   Equity(13 [ABC])    Equity(20 [ABT])    Equity(27 [ACE])    Equity(37 [ACN])    Equity(45 [ADBE])   ... Equity(3149 [XEL])  Equity(3150 [XL])   Equity(3151 [XLNX]) Equity(3156 [XOM])  Equity(3165 [XRX])  Equity(3171 [YELP]) Equity(3172 [YHOO]) Equity(3175 [YUM])  Equity(3180 [ZBH])  Equity(3197 [ZTS])
```

The next step is finding out the sector data for each symbol, so I used yahoo finance. The variance shown below is where I assign a number for each sector against each symbol based on the symbol index (equity number). So I have a numpy array of length 3198 and each element is filled with a number corresponding to the sector. It is worth noting that the above equities are in total 500 equities indeed as defined by the 'universe', and I tried a variant of the below to generate a numpy array only of length 500. Both give the same error (though index numbers are different of course as will be shown below).

So, this is the code I used to generate the sector data:

```
tickers = prices.columns.values.tolist() #tickers from prices columns in the form of 'Equity n ([symbol])'
tick_seq = [int(str(t).split('(')[1].split('[')[0]) for t in tickers] #get list of equity index (n)
tick_name = [str(t).split('[')[1][:-2] for t in tickers] #get list of symbol names
tick_tuple = list(zip(tick_seq,tick_name)) #collect index and symbol name to list of tuples
tick_list = [list(i) for i in tick_tuple] #convert list of tuples to list of lists

def get_sector(sym):
    try:
        sector = yf.Ticker(sym[1]).info['sector'] #use yahoo finance to get sector information
    except:
        sector = 'NoSector'
    return [sym[0], sym[1], sector]
    
with ThreadPoolExecutor() as t:
    sectors = list(t.map(get_sector, tick_list)) #returns list of lists, each inner list is [index, symbol, sector]

sectors_set = set([s[2] for s in sectors]) #get set of sectors
sectors_set.remove('NoSector')
sectors_set = {v:i for i,v in enumerate(sorted(sectors_set))} #assign a number for each sector
sectors_set['NoSector']=-1 # identify an unfound sector with -1
tmp = [s.append(sectors_set[s[2]]) for s in sectors] #append sector identifier number to each list; it becomes [index, symbol, sector, sec_no]
ix = [int(s[0]) for s in sectors] #extract again the indices of the symbols
val = [int(s[-1]) for s in sectors] #extract the sec_no for each index
sectors_np = np.zeros(max(ix)+1) #since equity indices are not sequential, we take the max found
sectors_np[:]=-1 #fill all as not found
sectors_np[ix]=val #fill the found sectors at their corresponding symbol index
sectors_np = sectors_np.astype(int) #convert the array to integer
```

The next step is to create a 'Classifier' as follows:

```
class Sector(Classifier):
    dtype = int64_dtype
    window_length = 1
    inputs = ()
    missing_value = -1

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = s_np #sector_np

    def _compute(self, arrays, dates, assets, mask):
        print('sector data shape: {}'.format(self.data.shape))
        print('assets shape: {}'.format(assets.shape))
        print('mask shape: {}'.format(mask.shape))
        return np.where(mask, self.data[assets], self.missing_value)
```

The last step is to create the factor, which I do as follows:

```
factor_start_date = universe_end_date - pd.DateOffset(years=2, days=2)
universe = AverageDollarVolume(window_length=120).top(500)
sector = Sector()
pipeline = Pipeline(screen=universe, domain=domain)

M1YR = Returns(window_length=252, mask=universe).demean(groupby=sector).rank().zscore()
pipeline.add(M1YR,'M1YR')

all_factors = engine.run_pipeline(pipeline, factor_start_date, universe_end_date)
```

And here I get an error on running the pipeline saying:

```
Cell In[210], line 14, in Sector._compute(self, arrays, dates, assets, mask)
     12 print('assets shape: {}'.format(assets.shape))
     13 print('mask shape: {}'.format(mask.shape))
---> 14 return np.where(mask, self.data[assets], self.missing_value)

IndexError: index 3198 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3198
```

And the prints I put in the _compute function of the class print the following:

```
sector data shape: (3198,)
assets shape: (3175,)
mask shape: (505, 3175)
```

I would really appreciate if you can help me out identifying what could be possibly wrong in here.
Thanks;

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer, and I hope someone can verify.
The solution lies in the `Sector()` `print` functions. Those `prints` tell us that the `Sector(Classifier)` is being passed `assets` of shape `(3175,)` and `mask` of shape `(505,3175)`. This means that all assets (not jut the top 500) are being passed to the classifier, and it would be logical then that the `compute` function returns an `index` error.

So, what I did is that I re-wrote the part to get the Sector information as will be shown below.
Another trick there was that the `assets` while of shape `(3175,)`, the maximum value in the `assets` was `3198`. Indeed though my sector acquiring function is looking only for the top 500 symbols, their index ranged from 0 to 3197. So the line `np.zeros(max(ix)+1)` returns an np array of size 3198 (indexed from 0 to 3197). If maximum `assets` index is 3198 and is used in the `Sector(classifier)`, it will return error then because `data[3198]` is out of bounds. So, I simply modify the line to be `np.zeros(max(ix)+2)`, so that indices work.

Below are my sector acquiring function, and the classifier class that don't produce an error any more. I hope if someone with more zipline insight to have a look and advise if indexing in this manner (while it works syntactically) would be semantically correct.

**Sector Acquiring Function**

```
def get_sector(sym):
    try:
        sector = yf.Ticker(sym[1]).info['sector'] #use yahoo finance to get sector information
    except:
        sector = 'NoSector'
    return [sym[0], sym[1], sector]

def build_sectors(prices, short_list=True):
    tickers = prices.columns.values.tolist() #tickers from prices columns in the form of 'Equity n ([symbol])'
    tick_seq = [int(str(t).split('(')[1].split('[')[0]) for t in tickers] #get list of equity index (n)
    tick_name = [str(t).split('[')[1][:-2] for t in tickers] #get list of symbol names
    tick_tuple = list(zip(tick_seq,tick_name)) #collect index and symbol name to list of tuples
    tick_list = [list(i) for i in tick_tuple] #convert list of tuples to list of lists
    
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv('sectors.csv')
        ix = df['symbol_seq'].tolist()
        val = df['sec_id'].tolist()
        sym_name = df['symbol'].tolist()
        if sym_name != tick_name:
            raise Exception('Symbol names stored on file are different from your dataset')
        if short_list == False:
            sym_seq = df['symbol_seq'].tolist()
            if sym_seq != tick_seq:
                raise Exception('Symbol sequences stored on file are different from your dataset')
    except:
        with ThreadPoolExecutor() as t:
            sectors = list(t.map(get_sector, tick_list)) #returns list of lists, each inner list is [index, symbol, sector]
    
        sectors_set = set([s[2] for s in sectors]) #get set of sectors
        sectors_set.remove('NoSector')
        sectors_set = {v:i for i,v in enumerate(sorted(sectors_set))} #assign a number for each sector
        sectors_set['NoSector']=-1 # identify an unfound sector with -1
        tmp = [s.append(sectors_set[s[2]]) for s in sectors] #append sector id number to each list; it becomes [index, symbol, sector, sec_no]
        ix = [int(s[0]) for s in sectors] #extract again the indices of the symbols
        val = [int(s[-1]) for s in sectors] #extract the sec_no for each index
        df = pd.DataFrame({'symbol_seq':[s[0] for s in sectors], 'symbol':[s[1] for s in sectors], 
                   'sector':[s[2] for s in sectors], 'sec_id': [s[3] for s in sectors]})
        df.to_csv('sectors.csv')

    if short_list:
        sectors_np = np.array(val)
    else:
        sectors_np = np.zeros(max(ix)+2) #since equity indices are not sequential, we take the max found
        sectors_np[:]=-1 #fill all as not found
        sectors_np[ix]=val #fill the found sectors at their corresponding symbol index
    sectors_np = sectors_np.astype(int) #convert the array to integer
    return sectors_np
```

**Sector Classifier Class**

```
class Sector(Classifier):
    dtype = int64_dtype
    window_length = 0
    inputs = ()
    missing_value = -1

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = build_sectors(prices, short_list=False)

    def _compute(self, arrays, dates, assets, mask):
        return np.where(mask, self.data[assets], self.missing_value)
```